# Term for the amount from which commission is calculated

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for the larger amount from which a salesman's commission might be calculated.

Something like **sale price** presupposes that his commission is calculated from that particular figure.

I have used **principal** before because it's a very similar concept to interest being calculated from the principal of a loan, but it's technically incorrect for this purpose.

I've considered **dividend** (i.e. dividend ÷ divisor = quotient) but this has other connotations

Whereas **multiplicand** (i.e. multiplicand × multiplier = product) is too obscure.

Anyone got a winner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider **[base](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/base)**

> a number that is multiplied by a rate or of which a percentage or fraction is calculated

Or possibly **base amount**.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, although in this context I would expect *base* to refer to a base salary before commissions, rather than the multiplier for the commission percentage.

Comment: It's for a variable in a computer program, so I've gone for CommissionBase.

Answer (score 0):

Gross is undiminished by deduction; an entire amount as opposed to net (of commission e.g.)

Comment: _Gross_ would be appropriate for somebody who earns a percentage of gross sales revenue, but some commission agreements are based on other figures.

Answer (score -1):

The most general term I have seen for the base value of commissions, tips, and related compensation is [*sales.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sales_%28accounting%29) Depending on the details of the compensation agreement, a more specific term like *gross, net, profit, receipts,* or *revenue* may be used, especially if you need to distinguish between two different methods. For example, you might generally refer to a percentage of **sales,** but differentiate between two people who earn a percentage of **gross** versus **net** or a percentage of **revenue** versus **profit.**